# Limit to number of WSO2 APIs

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is there any limit to the number of APIs that can be added to a certain API group in WSO2? I noticed that some of my later APIs were returning 404 but when I added the exact same API to another newly created group, the API worked correctly.

Comment: Do you know exactly how many API you have added to one tag group?

Comment: I had added 110 APIs.